# Subdomains not working in /etc/host

Tags: ubuntu, dns, ubuntu-12.04, host

I am trying to edit my /etc/hosts file on Ubuntu 12.04 so that a URL points to another ip address. This works just fine until I try a URL with a subdomain. Is there any solution for this? Could it also be that there is a dash in the subdomain?

Example:

```
127.0.0.1 domain.net #works
127.0.0.1 new-dev.domain.net #doesn't work
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: There is no reason why this shouldn't work. Is that exactly how you have written the entry in `/etc/hosts`? Do other entries work?

Comment: When I ping the server it points to localhost, but when I direct my browser to it, it doesn't seem to pick it up. Other entries do the same.

Comment: Can you check if your browser is configured to use a proxy server? The fact that the host is resolved to 127.0.0.1 when you use ping shows that the IP is read from /etc/hosts.

Comment: This apparently never got answered (the answer below about apache2 doesn't appear to be relevant). Can anyone maybe answer the question, because, like the OP, my pings seem to be trapped to 127.0.0.1, but Chrome still goes to the external subdomain, whereas if I trap just the top (www) domain, it works (i.e., the pings are trapped to 127.0.0.1, but now chrome won't go to the top (www) domain either. There seems to be some sort of processing difference in the browser for subdomains that circumvents /etc/hosts!

Answer (score -1):

You need create two virtual host in apache2 which look on path project

And this virtual host should contain

```
First virtualHost:
ServerAlias main_host.com
Second VirtualHolst
SercerAlias sub_dom.main_host.com
```